# Make alexa say something from a Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I am using https://github.com/hortinstein/node-dash-button to record some activity in my home. For example, I want to record time I go to bed every day. I am running node-dash-button application in my home network on a raspberry pi. When dash button is pressed I am making an entry in DynamoDB.

Now the problem is, there is no feedback when entry is made in DynamoDB. I have an Amazon Echo Dot. Is it possible that I trigger a Lambda function based on the entry I make in DynamoDB which eventually send a voice command to my Echo dot. For example: Entry of time 2200 Hours recorded. What I am looking for is a particular feature which I can use and develop on, any pointers or names will be helpful.

--
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As if now Alexa doesn't support Push Notification which is what needed in this case. Without waking up alexa, it is not possible to get any acknowledgement.

Answer (score 1):

There currently isn't a way to get Alexa to activate when you create a dynamodb record, however you could create a skill to read you the time when the record was made through a lambda function.

If you are ok with not using Alexa to get your notifications, you could use AWS' SNS service and a lambda function to push a notification to your phone when a record is made. Service is relatively cheap if there aren't many users.

**related docs**:

https://aws.amazon.com/sns/getting-started/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html

Comment: So notification is coming soon by AWS. https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/8cc45487-d5fb-413b-b6c7-eeea4794d10c/amazon-announces-notifications-for-alexa-feature-is-coming-soon-sign-up-to-stay-tuned

Until then, I created an SNS which is sending SMS. Thanks for your help.